# Understanding Why Request Doesn't work in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, request

I have built a small flask server and associated website. I am able to use the flask server to successfully local host the page and furthermore I am able to use the code `return str(request.form)` to view text that I placed in a text field after clicking a button.

Now I have written in my code that upon clicking the button of the FIRST html page one finds on my local host that they are redirected to another html page with almost identical code. For some reason however:

```
return str(request.form)
```

No longer displays values that I have inputted to the site. I kept trying to debug why and have ultimtely come to the conclusion that the flask request object DOES NOT behave the same way when called multiple times. Beyond that, I have no idea how to repair this.

Here it is: (Flask Python Code: )

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template
from flask import abort, redirect, url_for
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText



app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('minifile.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    return redirect(url_for('my_form2'))

@app.route('/a/')
def my_form2():
    return render_template('minifile2.html')
@app.route('/a/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form2_post():
    return str(request.form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML for minifile.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <form action="\" method='POST'>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" style="width: 210px;"/>

         <input type="Submit" name="" value="submit" style="width: 210px; background-color: black; color: white; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px;" />
    </form>
</body>




</html>
```

HTML for minifile2.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <form action="\" method='POST'>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" style="width: 210px;"/>

         <input type="Submit" name="" value="submit" style="width: 210px; background-color: black; color: white; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px;" />
    </form>
    This is text
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Redirects never include POST variables; you can include GET parameters but you  must do explicitly. This has nothing to do with Flask, however, that is how HTTP redirects work.

Comment: But both my html files have forms, and shouldn't str(request.form) display the table consisting of those forms? Regardless of how one ultimately arrived at the webpage itself?

Comment: The 'POST' code only activates, if I understand correctly, when the buttons on the sites are pressed

Comment: But did you actually fill anything in on the second form after redirecting to it?

Comment: Yes, manually I filled the form. Then I pressed the button again

Comment: Both your forms post to the root path, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second form posts back to the root path handler `/`:

```html
<form action="\" method='POST'>
```

You can see this in action on the Flask output to your console:

```html
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2015 13:08:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2015 13:08:16] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2015 13:08:21] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2015 13:08:21] "GET /a/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2015 13:08:26] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2015 13:08:26] "GET /a/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

On posting the first form served by `/`, the browser is redirected to `/a/` (the `POST` is served a 302 redirect, followed by a 200 response for the second form). POST-ing that form goes back to `/`. You can also use your browser developer tools to observe the network entries.

Rather than hardcode the action URL, use `url_for` and name your target:

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('my_form2_post') }}" method='POST'>
```